# if (basename(__FILE__) == xxx.php)... Stops Working When Included?

Tags: php

I'm trying to change the variable `$number` based on the page URL and if a get variable is present.  I have it working, but when the code is placed in a php file that is included it says `Notice: Undefined variable: number`

Here is what works while it is directly in the file test.php:

```
if(basename(__FILE__) == 'test.php' && ($_GET['ts'] == '1')){
    $number = "42";
}
```

So if the url is http://example.com/test.php?ts=1 the above will work perfectly.

This is what I'm having trouble with:

```
include("number.php");
```

When I add the line of code that worked into a file called `number.php` and include it like i did above into `test.php` it stops working.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: `if (basename(__FILE__); == xxx.php)` huh? why is that semi-colon in there, in the question title, is that part of the real code? If so, that's an end of execution character statement.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry about that you can see the original code in the first code block

Comment: Adding `echo basename(__FILE__);` to the script might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__FILE__` always returns the file name where it is. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.

So if the code is in `number.php`, then `__FILE__` will be `number.php`.

You could use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead, which returns the filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root.

Comment: how do I return only the file name without the path? thats the maine reason I was using `__FILE__`

Comment: @JoeBobby `basename` did it.

Answer (score 0):

`__FILE__`: The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved. **If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Hope it helped you.