# Does PHP 7 have an equivalent of array_value_last()?

Tags: php, arrays

This is genuine question (but also code golf for PHP devs).

I know `array_key_last()` exists in PHP.

I would like to use `array_value_last()` on `explode('/', __FILE__)` but... `array_value_last()` doesn't exist.

I am working inside a constrained environment (an included file which contains and runs a function, before returning data) and I have tried both:

- `array_pop(explode('/', __FILE__))`
- `end(explode('/', __FILE__))`

and neither of these work. (I don't know why they are not working).

> **N.B.** The sole purpose of the environment is to return a variable (either an array or a string). In this environment `array_pop(explode('/', __FILE__))` and `end(explode('/', __FILE__))` both result in a browser error: `Content Encoding Error An error occurred during a connection to example.com. Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.`
>
> Statements such as`echo`and other executing statements produce the same **Encoding Error**.

Here is my current code, which ***is*** working:

```
$My_Filename = explode('/', __FILE__)[(count(explode('/', __FILE__)) - 1)];
```

Is there a shorthand in PHP 7 to get the last value of an array?

Comment: There is a proposal for it https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_key_first_last

Comment: @ElzoValugi a) rfc is already merged b) OP asks for last __value__, not key.

Comment: the proposal was also for array_value_last

Comment: You know what is [mcve], right?

Comment: This is mcve - https://3v4l.org/ldhCT In it you can see that both `array_pop` and `end` __work as expected__. In your question you state that they do not work. __Show example__ when they do not work.

Comment: *"Both `array_pop($My_Array)` and `end($My_Array)` produce: **Content Encoding Error An error occurred during a connection to example.com. Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.**"* <- that would be useful to know beforehand (in the question) since this has a slight whiff of an XY problem about it now...

Comment: And you can't even `var_dump($My_Array)` to see what you have there before calling `array_pop`?

Comment: You could possibly debug to a log file (so you're not outputting anything)? ... or even perhaps send debugging info to `mail()` so you'd get an email. Personally I'd be more interested in finding out *why* `array_pop()` or `end()` don't work, what they're outputting that's causing the content encoding to trip up (maybe triggering an error/warning if your array isn't actually an array) than trying to find a workaround... I *suspect* there's something else going on that could be resolved.

Comment: _“Is there a shorthand in PHP 7 to get the last value of an array?”_ - shorter than _using_ the key `array_key_last` gives you to access the array element _by that key_ you mean …?

Comment: Not if you don’t actually store your array data in a variable first, no. But since you said you _tried_ array_pop/end with `$My_Array`, I was assuming that you somehow actually had one already. (And `end($My_Array)` _does_ of course work here, if you’d done `$My_Array = explode(…)` before.)

Comment: @04FS - I take your point about my inconsistent use of `$My_Array` in my question above. I have updated the question to ensure consistency throughout.

Comment: Using either array_pop or end with an array directly (instead of a variable) should get you a “Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference”. The content encoding error sounds like a subsequent error, _caused_ by that notice making its way into the output, that has probably messed with sending headers regarding page charset or something.

Comment: Excellent deduction. Yes, that sounds entirely plausible.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30596901/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible candidate for the code golf:

**Original:** `explode('/', __FILE__)[(count(explode('/', __FILE__)) - 1)]` // 59 characters

**Alternative:** `array_reverse(explode('/', __FILE__))[0]` // 40 characters

That represents a reduction of nearly **33%**.

I'm curious to know if there might be an even better shorthand.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with `end`

```
$latestValue = end($array); // Returns latest value in $array, setting the internal pointer to the last element 
reset($array); // Don't forget to reset the pointer!!!
```

Ok... if it doesn't work (that's very strange dude, big problem xD) you could try something like:

```
$aux = array_values($array); //No need to use this if it isn't an associative array
$size = count($aux);
$latestValue = $array[$size-1]; //Be careful with empty arrays
```

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault... Mmm... If that's what you're doing, I don't think there's another way to do properly. I think that we have said every existing option in Php.

Your problem is not really the code that you or us posted... it's something that don't let you use any useful method to get that value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `basename(__FILE__);` to get last part of the path. In general don't strive for this kind of one-liners - you won't gain anything in terms of performance, but loose code readability.

Both `array_pop()` and `end()` functions with expressions will give you a notice, because they will also try to modify variable (passed by reference) in current scope, and the message you get is coming from server or error handler (hidden details in production environment) - default interpreter display (better for dev) would give you: `<b>Notice</b>:  Only variables should be passed by reference in...`.